# glTexImage2D take long time in some PCs

Tags: c++, opengl, hardware-acceleration

**Background:**

1. Use DXVA2 to decode 4K 30FPS video,then pass the decoded frames directly to opengl for render.
2. The framework is GPU decode(DXVA2) then GPU render(Opengl),without copy back to CPU.

**Problem:**

1. I found in some PCs glTexImage2D take too long time(140ms).One PC's GPU is intel HD 5500 + Nivida GeFoce 940M.
2. But in some PCs it only takes 16ms.One PC's GPU is intel HD 5500 + AMD R7 M260.
3. All the PCs have the latest gpu driver updated.

**SourceCode:**

Below is DXVA2 decode source code.

```
static int dxva2_retrieve_data(AVCodecContext *s, AVFrame *frame)
{
    LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 surface =  (LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9)frame->data[3];
    InputStream        *ist = (InputStream *)s->opaque;
    DXVA2Context       *ctx = (DXVA2Context*)ist->hwaccel_ctx;
    D3DSURFACE_DESC    surfaceDesc;
    D3DLOCKED_RECT     LockedRect;
    HRESULT            hr;
    int                ret;

    IDirect3DSurface9_GetDesc(surface, &surfaceDesc);

    hr = IDirect3DSurface9_LockRect(surface, &LockedRect, NULL, D3DLOCK_READONLY);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Unable to lock DXVA2 surface\n");
        return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }

    picture->data[0] = (uint8_t*)LockedRect.pBits;
    picture->data[1] = (uint8_t*)LockedRect.pBits + LockedRect.Pitch * surfaceDesc.Height;
    frameWidth = frame->width;
    frameHeight = frame->height;
    //glFinish() <---- commentee suggestion
    DWORD start = GetTickCount();//test time
    Draw();//opengl draw        
    //glFinish() <---- commentee suggestion
    DWORD end = GetTickCount();//test time
    printf("draw time:%d\n", end - start);//test time
    start = end - start;
    picture->data[0] = nullptr;
    picture->data[1] = nullptr;

    IDirect3DSurface9_UnlockRect(surface);
    return 0;
fail:
    return ret;
}
```

Below is Draw function's code.

```
void Draw()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glClearColor(0.0, 255, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(g_program);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, picture->data[0]);
    glUniform1i(y, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, picture->data[1]);
    glUniform1i(uv, 1);

    DrawHorizontal();

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

**Question：**

Who can tell me why the same code have the different result at different PCs?
Or give me some advices?

Comment: Since those are both laptops with dual GPUs, I'd make sure a proper GPU is used in both cases first.

Comment: Your question contradicts itself: You first describe that you don't copy the image data back to the cpu, but why do you need to call `glTexImage2D` afterwards? This function can only be used to upload CPU data to the GPU. From a performance point of view: If the size of frames do not change between frames, you should allocate texture memory just once by calling `glTexImage2D` and then upload data with `glTexSubImage2D` in every frame.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,if do not use glTexImage2D,what do I can use?FrameBuffer?

Comment: Your time measuring is broken. OpenGL is asynchrounous and may perform gl-commands any time it wishes. To make it right do glFinish before starting and stopping the clocks.

Comment: Thank you,I have added the glFinish,but the result is almost the same.It take 120ms to draw one frame.
can you give me some other advice?